# How to load the Python Parser in Pharo Smalltalk?

Tags: python, parsing, smalltalk, pharo

What would be the proper way to load the PythonParser project in Pharo 3.0? The current configuration is broken with the following message:

> The symbolic version #stable is not defined in
>   ConfigurationOfPythonParser for the current platform. Possible
>   symbolic version values include: #(#bleedingEdge #development)

I'm looking for a Python parser that can be used in Smalltalk and give me access to line and file informations about each artefact of the analysed code.

Comment: The Python Parser should work and we are currently improving it. I'm very interested in your feedback about it, please send me private emails.

Answer (score 2):

The error you are seeing means that the configuration hasn't been prepared for 3.0 and that the project will very likely not work without errors (though it's possible that it will work more or less). You can force a load with all the latest code by using `#bleedingEdge` but you have to be aware that loading of dependencies might fail for the same reason (which would require you to hack the configuration; that's something you don't want to do if you're not familiar with configurations). So try this:

```
(ConfigurationOfPythonParser project version: #bleedingEdge) load.
```

Comment: Still get an error, bleedingEdge is not defined in the configuration :(

Answer (score 1):

This will probably work (you might need a github account):

```
Gofer it
    smalltalkhubUser: 'Pharo' project: 'MetaRepoForPharo30/';
    configurationOf: 'PythonParser';
    loadStable
```

Comment: This currently leads to an error under OS X. We're investigating. I'll report back when we've resolved the issue.

Comment: Same to Windows, please let us know if you have any progress

Comment: Still doesn't install: FileDoesNotExist: File @ \tmp\github-ThierryGoubierSmaCCe01229b5f9d430e5744225764dcccbbf99bb130e.zip I think the MCGitHubRepository wasn't tested on Windows then hardcodes /tmp reference like if everyone is going to install on Linux

Comment: Please use #loadStable instead of #loadDevelopment.